# How do I not allow full screen for a video(from my pc) in a iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

`<iframe allowFullscreen="false" src="../../resurse/test_video.mp4"></iframe>`
This is what I've got right now but it doesn't work and I can't find a solution so I wonder if it is possible.

Comment: Why not use the html5 video tag inside the iframe?

Comment: This iframe is linked to a image map and I don't know how to link a video tag to it

Answer (score 0):

Use the iframe tag without allowFullscreen to disable the button on the player

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ex</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Wont go fullScreen</h2>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rwCJvSKzQkc"></iframe>

<h2>Wil go fullScreen because we gave it allowfullscreen property</h2>
<iframe allowfullscreen="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rwCJvSKzQkc"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```